# Project Builld error in xamarin.forms

Tags: build, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I create a xamarin.forms application runs on ios and android platform firstly in android it gives me a error of `io exception` but after solve that error it gives me a following error . I found many possible way but still it gives me a following error.

> "obj\Debug\Test.Droid.dll;obj\Debug\Test.Droid.dll" is an invalid
>   value for the "OutputAssembly" parameter of the "Csc" task.  Multiple
>   items cannot be passed into a parameter of type
>   "Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem".    Test.Droid

If there is any who has answer or aware of this kindly please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm getting the same thing right now @Deep Soni. Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: @Chucky I am still not able to fix this. I will let you know if I will get solution. Can you please suggest me if you get any solution?

Comment: this solution worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/47771128/812013. Namely, changing to link Sdk Assemblies Only. I'm not sure what the drawback of this is, or whether I'll leave it like that, but as a short term fix, it worked.