# Error in project Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, compiler-errors, cross-platform

I am doing a project and I don't know why this error is appearing:

> "obj\Debug\ iDonde_v2.Android.dll; obj \Debug \iDonde_v2.Android.dll"
>   is not a valid value for the "OutputAssembly" parameter of the "Csc"
>   task. You can not lose multiple elements in a parameter of type
>   "Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem"

I searched but I didn't find a solution

Comment: Did you try to clean and rebuild the solution ?

Comment: @Argoth yes I did it and nothing. Also I close and open again visual studio and nothing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin Android Build Failed "Invalid value for outputAssembly"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770465/xamarin-android-build-failed-invalid-value-for-outputassembly)

Comment: I believe that the answer for this question can be found here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770465/xamarin-android-build-failed-invalid-value-for-outputassembly