# How to set Project Linking in VS2019

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019

I basically got the same error as this post from 3 years ago: [Xamarin Android Build Failed "Invalid value for outputAssembly"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770465/xamarin-android-build-failed-invalid-value-for-outputassembly) but I don't understand the solution and was looking for help.

After not changing any code in my master branch, today in VS2019 and Xamarin.Forms 4.4.0.991477, I went to build my app in android, when I got this error

```
obj\Debug\...\Appname.Droid.dll is an invalid value for the 
"OutputAssembly" parameter of the "Csc" task. Multiple items 
cannot be passed into a parameter of type 
"Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem".
```

Now I don't understand the solution from the previous post,

> You have to set your Project Linking to Sdk Assemblies Only and set support architecture to armeabi - v7 and x86.
>   After try to clean and rebuild the project

I don't really understand how to go about doing this, where do I go in VS to access these settings? And also is this the best answer in 2020, or is there another one? Thanks!

Comment: look in the Android project settings

Comment: I found the SDK linking but not the second part...

Anyways, my boss told me to try and find another solution other than adding the SDK linking, any suggestions?

Comment: also in [Android project properties you can select the used cpu architectures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/cpu-architectures?tabs=windows#how-to-specify-supported-architectures)